# Assigning incremental values based on an unique value of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add an incremental value to a column based on specific values of another column in a dataframe. So that...

```
col A   col B
 A        0
 B        1
 C        2
 A        3
 A        4
 B        5
```

Would become something like this:

```
col A   col B
 A        1
 B        2
 C        3
 A        1
 A        1
 B        2
 C        3
```

Have tried using groupby function but cant really get my head around setting incremental values on column B.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I think need [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df['col B'] = pd.factorize(df['col A'])[0] + 1
print (df)
  col A  col B
0     A      1
1     B      2
2     C      3
3     A      1
4     A      1
5     B      2
```

Another solution:

```
df['col B'] = pd.Categorical(df['col A']).codes + 1
print (df)
  col A  col B
0     A      1
1     B      2
2     C      3
3     A      1
4     A      1
5     B      2
```

Comment: Thanks. 1st one didn't work but 2nd one did. One downside of pd.Categorical appears that the values assigned are of random order and not incremental. Any suggestions on overcoming this? Ty

Comment: Not sure if understand. Why first not working? There is different ordering of values in column `A` ?

Comment: Sorry my bad, first one works fine as well and the values set based on the order of col A - which is perfect. Thanks!